# Using Excel range of cell values for ms query single paramter

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an excel sheet with two fields: list of user id, and corresponding create date. I want to query from an external database having around million records by only returning records where user_id in (?). How can i pass a range of id's like $A1:A17 as the single parameter to the query?

Answer (score 1):

One option to achieve the same result using another method would be to create a [temporary table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#autoId1) with just one column for user_id.

Then you could run the query and do:

```
where user_id in (select user_id from my_temp_table)
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to find a way to achieve the above result without creating a temp_table. Is there a way to say: WHERE user_id in (?) with ? being a range of cell values?

Comment: @user2781746 Here is a blog post that may be helpful for you: http://excelusergroup.org/blogs/nickhodge/archive/2008/01/24/importing-data-with-parameters-odbc.aspx. If you don't get anywhere with this and want some help with the VBA syntax to create the temp table let me know.